# Insertion sort runtime error

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

I created a basic array and tried to sort it using an insertion sort but I get these errors as I run the program. There are no errors after compiling

> ./insertionsort.c: line 3: $'\r': command not found
>
> ./insertionsort.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
> '/insertionsort.c: line 4: `void sort(int *array, int n);

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort(int *array, int n);
void swap(int array1, int array2);


void main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6};
    int n = sizeof(arr);

    sort(arr, n);
}

void sort(int *array, int n)
{
    int i, j;

    printf("Array before sorting: ");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", &array[i]);

    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=i; j>0; j--)
        {
            if (array[j-1] > array[j])
                swap(array[j], array[j-1]);
        }
    }

    printf("Array after sorting: ");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d ", &array[i]);
}

void swap(int array1, int array2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = array1;
    array1 = array2;
    array2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling your source file? How are you running it? Are you on Linux or Windows? Are you using an IDE or the command line?

Comment: I'm on windows and I'm using the cygwin terminal

Comment: Well, then, I think you can just use `gcc -o main main.c` where `main.c` would be the source file containing the code from above. And then just type `./main` to run you program. I'm not seeing where the problem could be, but maybe I'm missing something. Could you please try that? Or are you using another method to builld/run your application?!

Comment: i didn't have gcc but i had g++, thanks!

Comment: So...did it work with no errors then?

Comment: Yes, got rid of all of them

Comment: Great, happy hacking then..and don't forget to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to do

```
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
```

as `sizeof(arr)` would give you the total number of bytes needed by your array.

Also, you're printing pointers. So you can remove the `&` in your print statements:

```
printf("%d ", array[i]);
```

Lastly, you're passing by value to your `swap` function. So the original array will not be modified. You might want a signature like this:

```
void swap(int *array1, int *array2);
```

I don't get any error running your program, only warnings for your `printf`, the reason being the one mentioned above. You should compile/run your program something like this: `gcc -o main main.c` where `main.c` would be the source file containing the code from above. And then just type `./main`.

Comment: how can I fix the problem of passing by value to my swap function? I tried adding an asterix before array1 and array2 in the swap function but i just get more errors

Comment: @Michael, you must also change the call of your `swap` in the `sort` function. Hint: it has something to do with pointers.

Comment: thank you for the help, I can't figure out the swap function (it's late), so I just took it out and put the contents of it right in my if statement. Works perfect now

Answer (score 1):

From the program name `./insertionsort.c` in your error message, I guess you are trying to execute your source code directly, which isn't normal procedure.

I think you should type the name of your compiled binary file instead your source code to  your terminal to run the program.

Comment: That would be interesting. But would the `.c` file be executable by default?! Shouldn't he get a `permission denied` instead? I'm guessing he didn't just `chmod +x insertionsort.c` by mistake.

Comment: @Mihai This execution is performed on Windows, on which such `chmod` isn't required to execute files.